# How to import Pytorch model into MATLAB

Tags: python, matlab, neural-network, pytorch

I've created a model within Pytorch and I wish to transfer it to MATLAB, a minimal example is shown

```
import torch.nn as nn
import torch
class cnn(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(cnn, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(10, 1),
            nn.ReLU(True)
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        out = self.fc1(x)
        return out
the_net = cnn()
torch.save(the_net,'desperation.h5')
```

Within MATLAB I then call

```
net = importKerasLayers('desperation.h5')
```

This gives the error message

```
Error using importKerasLayers (line 104)
Unable to read HDF5 file 'desperation.h5'. The error message was: 'The filename specified was either
not found on the MATLAB path or it contains unsupported characters.''
```

The file is on the path and I am able to load the model back into Python. What I really want is any solution that allows me to transfer the model from Pytorch into MATLAB without manually copying all of the weights.

I am running MATLAB 2018b, Python 3.6 and Pytorch 0.4.0

Comment: Does importKerasLayers have the functionality to read pytorch weights?

Comment: I'm not sure, best I can tell torch.save is just saving in pytorch format no matter what ending you put on it which is why this isn't working. At any rate, weights are just floating point numbers so the main thing is the structure which contains the weights. This is why I want to put it into keras format first so that matlab can understand the structure.

Comment: have you looked at onnx?

Comment: I have but I couldn't figure out how to load an onnx model into MATLAB.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using this tool in the past with some success: https://github.com/albanie/mcnPyTorch to go from Pytorch to MatConvNet.